# How can i solve backward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'retain_variables'?

Tags: python, pytorch

I write the code following below but I got this error:

```
TypeError: backward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'retain_variables'
```

My code is:

```
def learn(self, batch_state, batch_next_state, batch_reward, batch_action):
    outputs = self.model(batch_state).gather(1, batch_action.unsqueeze(1)).squeeze(1)
    next_outputs = self.model(batch_next_state).detach().max(1)[0]
    target = self.gamma*next_outputs + batch_reward
    td_loss = F.smooth_l1_loss(outputs, target)
    self.optimizer.zero_grad()
    td_loss.backward(retain_variables = True)
    self.optimizer.step()
```

Comment: It should be [`retain_graph=True`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.backward).

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same problem. This solution worked for me.

```py
td_loss.backward(retain_graph = True)
```

It worked.

Answer (score 2):

As [a_guest mentions in the comments:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55564676/how-can-i-solve-backward-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-retain-variables/57033039#comment97829146_55564676)

> It should be retain_graph=True.